# concatenate ranges using join

Tags: c++, concatenation, g++, std-ranges, c++23

trying to join (concat) ranges using g++14. Is there a way to do this ?

```
#include <ranges>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    const vector<string> v = {"1","2","3"};

    const auto vv = {
        "{",
        v | views::join_with(','),
        "}"
    };

    const string buf = vv | views::join | ranges::to<string>();

}
```

Error:

```
prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:15:5: error: unable to deduce 'const std::initializer_list<auto>' from '{"{", std::ranges::views::__adaptor::operator|<_Partial<std::ranges::views::_JoinWith, char>, const std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >&>(v, ((const std::ranges::views::__adaptor::_RangeAdaptor<std::ranges::views::_JoinWith>*)(& std::ranges::views::join_with))->std::ranges::views::__adaptor::_RangeAdaptor<std::ranges::views::_JoinWith>::operator()<char>(',')), "}"}'
   15 |     };
      |     ^
prog.cc:15:5: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter 'auto' ('const char*' and 'std::ranges::join_with_view<std::ranges::ref_view<const std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, std::ranges::single_view<char> >')
```

Comment: I was hoping vv could be seen as a range of ranges. Just wanted to somehow concat ranges, as there is no views::concat() function in C++23.

Comment: string literal isn't a range

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know how to wrap the joined string you can use `std::format`

```
std::format("{{{}}}", vv);
```

note that `std::format` uses a format string with `{}` to place arguments which follow the format string, thus the inner most `{}` will be replaced by `vv`. To escape a brace, double braces are used, hence `{{` and `}}` left and right of `{}`. [godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/69dvjPMzf) of the full example.

To get rid of the verbose `std::sting("...")`, consider using `using namespace std::literals;` which allows for `"..."s` instead.

Answer (score 1):

wish it were less verbose.

```
#include <ranges>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    const vector<string> v = {"1","2","3"};

    const auto vv = {
        string("{"),
        v | views::join_with(',') | ranges::to<string>(),
        string("}")
    };

    const string buf = vv | views::join | ranges::to<string>();

}
```

Comment: It could be less verbose (and more efficient) with [`operator""sv()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/operator%22%22sv).

Answer (score 0):

C++26 has views::concat !

```
#include <ranges>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    const vector<string> v = {"1","2","3"};

    const string buffer = views::concat(
        "{",
        v | views::join_with(','),
        "}"
    ) | views::join | ranges::to<string>();

}
```